# error C3861: popen, pclose: identifier not found in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I get the error "error C3861: popen: identifier not found", if I run through vs code then everything works, but if I run through microsoft vs then the program does not want to compile. How to fix it?

code (c++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::string result = "";

    FILE* pipe = popen("some command 2>&1", "r"); //error

    char buffer[128];
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe); //error

    std::cout << "res :" << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipe-handle-inheritance?redirectedfrom=MSDN for pipe handling in MS Windows. popen is a posix function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If you are on Windows, it might be _popen() and _pclose()

Try this:

```
FILE* pipe = _popen("some command 2>&1", "r");
```